# Unit Testing Firebase Database with Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, mockito

I have created an app that allows users to create a transaction. When this transaction is created it is added to the database (Firebase Realtime Database). Once a transaction is created, a series of approvals have to be made before the transaction is carried out.

In order to approve a transaction, a user must click on the transaction on the transaction requests page which displays the desired transactions. Once a user clicks on this transaction the user is shown the relevant dialog box. When a user clicks the "approve" button on this dialog box, the value of the corresponding "flag" in the database is set to true.

I am trying to write a test using Mockito to test that this flag is indeed being set to true but I am struggling to do so. I have watched multiple videos on unit testing in android studio on youtube and have read through all the posts on here that involve firebase unit testing with android studio but I have still been unable to carry out my desired test.

As my research has lead me to a dead end I was hoping someone on here could either send me in the right direction to some sample code that I have not yet seen, or better yet help me write my desired test.

The code that I am trying to test is within this class:

```
public class Request extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Request";

//Firebase Stuff
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference start, ref;
DatabaseReference user;

RecyclerView recycler_menu;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

Dialog custDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request);

    final String passedEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("Email");

    //Init Firebase
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    start = database.getReference("Transaction");
    ref = database.getReference("User");

    //Load Menu
    recycler_menu = findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadMenu();
}

private void loadMenu() {
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Transaction, TransRequestHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Transaction, TransRequestHolder>(Transaction.class, R.layout.trans_item, TransRequestHolder.class, start) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(TransRequestHolder viewHolder, final Transaction model, int position) {
            final String passedUserType= getIntent().getStringExtra("userType");
            final String passedEmail= getIntent().getStringExtra("Email");
            final String receiver = model.getReceiver().replace('.', ' ');
            final String shopA = model.getShopA().replace('.', ' ');

            //custB
            if(passedEmail.equalsIgnoreCase(model.getReceiver()) && model.getCustflag() == false) {
                viewHolder.txtTransactionA.setText(model.getAmount());
                viewHolder.txtTransactionC.setText(model.getCurrency());
                viewHolder.txtTransactionR.setText(model.getReceiver());
                final Transaction clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(android.view.View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Request.this, "Receiving: " + shopA, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String key = model.getKey();
                        custDialog = new Dialog(Request.this);
                        custDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_template);
                        final EditText Write = custDialog.findViewById((R.id.write));
                        Button Approve = custDialog.findViewById(R.id.approve);

                        Write.setEnabled(true);
                        Approve.setEnabled(true);

                        Approve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                String newShopB = Write.getText().toString().replace(".", " ");
                                start.child(key).child("custflag").setValue(true);
                                start.child(key).child("shopB").setValue(newShopB);
                                Toast.makeText(Request.this, "CustB Approval", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                custDialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                        custDialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }
            //shopA
            else if (passedEmail.equalsIgnoreCase(model.getShopA()) && (model.getCustflag() == true && model.getShopAflag() == false)) {
                viewHolder.txtTransactionA.setText(model.getAmount());
                viewHolder.txtTransactionC.setText(model.getCurrency());
                viewHolder.txtTransactionR.setText(model.getReceiver());
                final Transaction clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(android.view.View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Request.this, "Receiving: " + shopA, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String key = model.getKey();
                        //Dialog option number one
                        customDialog("Transaction Approval", "Are you sure you want to approve this transaction?", "cancel", "okMethod2", passedEmail, key);
                    }
                });
            }
            //shopB
            else if (passedEmail.equalsIgnoreCase(model.getShopB()) && (model.getShopAflag() == true && model.getShopBflag() == false)) {
                viewHolder.txtTransactionA.setText(model.getAmount());
                viewHolder.txtTransactionC.setText(model.getCurrency());
                viewHolder.txtTransactionR.setText(model.getReceiver());
                final Transaction clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(android.view.View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Request.this, "Receiving: " + shopA, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        final String key = model.getKey();
                        //Dialog option number one
                        customDialog("Transaction Approval", "Are you sure you want to approve this transaction?", "cancel", "okMethod3", passedEmail, key);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    };
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

I hope I have provided enough information. I would appreciate any help anyone can give me.

Comment: Unit testing a database is not a unit test.

Comment: I would like to add that I have also read through all the guides on the Android Developers website. From a combination of these resources I have carried out a basic unit test to test that the activity is indeed launching. I also know that these flags work as I've tested them manually, however this project requires me to test them using unit testing.

Comment: @Neijwiert Well now I certainly feel dumb.. What kind of test would you call it?

Comment: What I'm saying is that testing a database is not unit testing, but integration testing. In a unit test you would mock the databases.

Comment: @Neijwiert ah right yes, sorry it has been a long day. Yes I have changed my question/tags to reflect what I meant. I am trying to use Mockito to do this.